# Issue when zooming on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I zoom in and out of my page the elements get weird.

Everything works but a container div (which is a color overlay over the image background). When you zoom in, or you go to mobile the div does not continue to the bottom of the page like it should. Instead, it shows the background image at the bottom without the image overlay.

Code:

```
#container {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  background-image: url(../img/d2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block">
         Content
    </div>       
</div>
```

I already tried the 100% height property on the overlay, and it didn't work. This is particularly an issue with mobile as well.

Comment: For starters, you're missing a `#` in your id selector in the CSS: `#container {...`

Comment: Ok, the issue has nothing to do with the missing #. I simply forgot to add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will probably be with the way you are doing this, your css shows the container as having a height and width of 100%, however (depending on you how you've structured your html) the container will only make 100% of the browser window and not of the web page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think fixing your CSS as Oscar suggested is a good starting point. Making that change, it seems like things are working correctly, but I'm a bit unclear on the issue.

```
#container {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://www.wallpick.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Smokey-Abstract-Wallpaper-Wallpaper-HD.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v495J/1/)